# Entity Framework query never returns

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a very simple EF query below that never returns.  The call to Any() just hangs.

```
if (!_context.SalesRoundRobinAssignments.Any()) return salesPeopleIds.First();
```

When I look at the sql profiler I don't see that query being executed however I do see the following.

```
SQL: BatchStarting  select serverproperty('EngineEdition')
SQL: BatchCompleted select serverproperty('EngineEdition')
```

I've also tried adding this before the query but nothing gets written to the output window aside from the same serverproperty query shown above.

```
_context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Any ideas what else I can look at to figure out what's going on?

Comment: If this is the first query using your DbContext, it may be trying to initialize your database.

Comment: It is in this case, but in many other places in code, the first query doesn't just hang and never return.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the connection string from your web.config/app.config that your **Entity Framework Context** uses to connect with the database? The query can be executing in another database and that's why you don't see nothing with the SQL profile.

Try to debug and see in execution time, which connection string your application is passing to **string connectionString** parameter:

```cs
 public YourDBContext(string connectionString): base(connectionString)
 {
 }
```

Comment: It's not the connection string.  As I said, I DO see commands being executed in sql profiler when I run it.  Just not the query that I'm trying to execute.  And if it was the connection string it would timeout after a minute saying the server couldn't be found.  That's not happening.  It just hangs and never returns.

Comment: Please, could you try _context.SalesRoundRobinAssignments.Load(); before you call Any() to see the behavior? Load will bring to memory all rows that you have in SalesRoundRobinAssignments table. Does other Entity Framework operations work in your project?

Comment: Actually, I'm noticing now that EF doesn't appear to be executing any query when it's called from this project.  EF is used in a data layer (separate project) which is referenced by multiple projects.  When called in any of the other projects which consist of asp.net webforms, mvc and console apps, it works fine.  But for some reason in this single case, a console app, it doesn't appear to work.  I'm referencing the same version of EF that the other uses.  Not sure what else to look for.

Comment: When you try to test this app, do you connect to Prod or Dev database? I keep thinking that the problem is something with the App.config, since it`s a console app. Do you get some error or nothing happens when you run the app?

Comment: It's connecting to our prod db.  No error.  If I step through it as soon as I hit F10 on the line for the Any() query it just never returns.  No error, nothing.

Comment: Do you know a tool called LinqPad: https://www.linqpad.net/? Download it, connect with the same credentials that your connection string uses, then try to run the Any() and see what happens. I use this program every day, it's a powerful tool.

Comment: How big is your SalesRoundRobinAssignments table? Do you have Context.Database.CommandTimeout  configured in your data layer project? Sorry about all the questions... I'm trying to brainstorm with you to see if we can find the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate it.  It only has 4 records and 3 columns per row.

Comment: I really think it's somehow tied to the console app that's referencing that project.  I'm just not sure what setting would cause this.

Comment: Try to create a new class that inherit from DbContext, create the DbSet to SalesRoundRobinAssignments then use this new DbContext to .Any(), if works, the problem is some configuration on the DbContext that is referencing  your data layer. I also recommend some kind of bounded context, if you don't need all datasets that your data layer uses, you could create a new context containing only the entitys that your console app needs.